# Why do we need the Third Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know the statement "The third law of thermodynamics states that the entropy of a system at absolute zero is a well-defined constant. This is because a system at zero temperature exists in its ground state so that its entropy is determined only by the degeneracy of the ground state."

But I don't yet understand it's a function. I saw in the accepted answer of this post that it plugs a loophole in second law "[Is the third law of thermodynamics a non-essential law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401951/is-the-third-law-of-thermodynamics-a-non-essential-law)" but I don't get what loophole it's fixing.